# Laravel4 Eager Loading not possible

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, eager-loading

I've got following query which beats the crap out of my database, because it makes a a single query for every relation:

```
$projects = $this->project->all()->sortBy(function ($item) {
  return $item->votes()->count();
  }, SORT_REGULAR, true)->take(30);
```

I tried many different ways:

`$projects = $this->project->with('Vote')->all()->sortBy(...)->take(30);`
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()

`$projects = $this->project->with('Vote')->get()->sortBy(...)->take(30);`
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Vote()

...

In the template I'm looping over the projects and use `$project->votes()->count()`

What is the correct way to do the eager loading?

Comment: Sorry! I've deleted the answer because it won't work, I'll post if I can make it working.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I'll try a different solution!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be the `all()` in the middle. Try getting rid of the `all()` and adding `get()` at the end. Furthermore, you can use e.g. `Project::` to make an Eloquent query, if you don't want to call an instance.

```
$projects = Project::with('vote')->sortBy(...)->take(30)->get();
```

That should solve it, I think. If you don't need any other project data, but rather the votes, than you might also be able to do a `groupBy` instead of looping through everything and then doing a `count()`.

Comment: This gives me `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortBy()`

Comment: Using `Project::` instead of `$this->project`, does that work? Did you make sure you have created a `Project` model which extends Eloquent?

Comment: I have different Project Models this is why i get my Project Model like this `public function __construct(){
        $this->project = App::make('Project');
    }`
Works fine for all other purposes, can't say if this is the problem.

Comment: But what does `$projects = Project::with('vote')->sortBy(...)->take(30)->get();` output with `get()` only at the end?

Comment: Nothing because I get this error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortBy()`

Comment: Try orderBy instead of sortBy. sortBy must be use on a collection object.